# Activity vs Service for Sound Pool?

Tags: android

I want to add a sound pool to my app, but where should I put it, in an activity or a service?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Can you elaborate the sound pool functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better use a service for long lasting and non user interaction process .
If you want to stop the sound when the activity is destroyed or in background use an Activity .

Answer (score 0):

What do mean by sound pool? Basically a Service is used when you have some time-comsuming calculations to be done and user interaction is not necessary. An activity requires user interaction. It depends on your plans for the sound pool.